# What am I doing wrong in this php regular expression?

Tags: php

I have a problem. I don't know what could be the cause. What I want to do is to know if an element of an array has a certain word, and I use this regular expression `/.*example.*/`, and this is the code:

```
$array = ['example1', '2example', 'no'];

$matches = [];
$var = "example";

foreach($array as $element)
{
      preg_match("/.*$var.*/", $element, $matches);
}
```

But when I run the above code and see the value of `$matches` it is an empty array. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you showing `$matches`? If you do it after the loop, it will only contain the matches from the last iteration, and `no` doesn't match. You need to check it inside the loop. See https://ideone.com/5pCHEl

Comment: @Barmar You are right, I did what you said and what you said happened, is there any way to make the `$matches` variable not only have the match of the last iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two variables. One is the result of the current match, and another is a list of all the matches. After each call you can push the result of the current match to the list.

```
$array = ['example1', '2example', 'no'];

$matches = [];
$var = "example";

foreach($array as $element)
{
    if (preg_match("/.*$var.*/", $element, $match)) {
        $matches[] = $match[0];
    }
}

print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are looping through your `$array` and probably print the result after the loop.

So `$matches` just includes the matching elements of the last item in your `$array`.
But because 'no' is the last element, and it doesn't fulfill the regex requirements, `$matches` is empty.

To have a better understanding of what is happening, try to use `print_r($matches)` within your loop, after you called `preg_matches()`.

And after that, try to call it after your loop and see the difference.

Comment: This is the result using `var_dump` https://ideone.com/5pCHEl